# Mule ESB integration with web applications

Tags: mule

We have more than 5 corporate applications running on different servers with technologies like spring, struts communication between these application is point to point. We are planning to migrate this to ESB using Mule.

I didnt quite understand how mule works i have few doubts,

1. Mule is running in a different server do i need to deploy all my 5 aplications into the mule server.
2. I have spring application delployed on a tomcat server how this application is going to receive messages through mule or what are the configuration changes i need to do in my server or mule server.

Any advice or tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

You need not deploy all you 5 applications in the Mule Server.

You said that all your application are currently point to point (which means that all are talking/communicating now through http protocol), similarly you can also use mule's http endpoints to communicate with all the 5 applications.

I.e. the spring application talking to another spring application can be modified to  Spring application talking to Mule and Mule in turn talking to another Spring application .

You must learn the basics from the Documentation

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Fundamentals --> browse through the navigation on the lefthand side.

Answer (score 1):

Mule is an integration tool. you no need to change any of your existing applications. All you need is to develop an mule  application which can do the mediation/orchestration.

For connecting with your spring application you no need to change any configuration you need to use http:outbound connector inside your mule flow

Just go through http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference

Answer (score 1):

So mule is based on SOA principle, so your 5 corporate service need not to be their in a single system. so if you want to consume the service/functionality of any of your 5 application, expose those service as web service, cloud be soap or rest. And you can call those service inside your mule. so in this case you have to create only 5 connection and where ever required you can refer to those connection inside mule configuration file.

Comment: would you provide any tutorial or write up shows the process of doing such thing...

Answer (score 0):

@saravanan shanmugavel you need to use Mule ESB to orchestrate the communication between these application...ESB came into the picture to remove your point to point communication...you can create a proxy service for each of your service and one flow which will orchestrate communication between all...

Answer (score 0):

All  you need to do is change the application that is configurable according to mule server.

Please refer below link that will be helpful for understanding of mule that helps you better orchestrate communication between all.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/